# Python.exe - Error del sistema

Tags: python

Hoy quise seguir practicando `Python`, y me encuentro con este mensaje:

> python.exe - Error del sistema

El programa no puede inciarse porque falta `api-ms-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll` en el equipo. Intente reinstalar el programa para corregir este problema.

Ya intente desinstalando `python` y volviendolo a instalar, pero no cambia en nada, ¿Alguna sugerencia? Muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: Hola Facu ¿Que versión de Windows usas?

Comment: Hola, estoy usando w7 en esta pc

Comment: La dll que te falta proviene de [Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=48145). En principio bastaría con instalarlo, aunque según [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33265663/api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll-is-missing-when-opening-microsoft-office-file) el sitio en inglés debes instalar previamente la actualización [KB2999226](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows). Otra posibilidad más remota es que tengas corrompido C++ Redistributable 2015...

Comment: Se solucionó, muchas gracias!